# % of New Email Addresses Per Month

Tags: sql

how to create a result that has % of new customer emails in a given month

email addresses = email
date = created_at

note: created_at is in unix code

pseudo code could be
1 - count of distinct emails between date x and date y (denominator)
2 - count of distinct emails between date x and date y where email is not between date a and date x (numerator)

help! thx!

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using; (2) provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the pseudo-code by aggregating at the email level and then aggregating again:

```
select sum(between_xy * (1 - between_ax)) / sum(between_xy)
from (select email,
             max(case when created_at between $x and $y then 1 else 0 end) as between_xy,
             max(case when created_at between $a and $x then 1 else 0 end) as between_ax
      from t
      group by email
     ) t;
```

select count(distinct case when created_at between $x and $y)
from t

Comment: Thx Gordon, appreciate your response.